# Is it possible to debug Iron Python with the Visual Studio Code Python Extension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, ironpython

Is it possible to debug an Iron Python Script with the Visual Studio Code Python Extension?

I´ve set the Iron Python 2.7.11 Interpreter and tried to start to debug a small example script from the iron python docs.

```
import re
re.findall(r'\bf[a-z]*', 'which foot or hand fell fastest')
re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+) \1', r'\1', 'cat in the the hat')
```

But nothing happens, the breakpoints were not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debug function was provided by the `Python extension`.

While the `Python extension` depends on:

> all actively supported [versions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python#python-extension-for-visual-studio-code) of the language: >=3.6

`Iron Python 2.7.11 Interpreter` looks like not supported.